# Wakatime Stats Tracker doesn't work in my GitHub profile README.md

Tags: github, readme, wakatime

So I wanted to add the Wakatime Section in my Github profile README.md but it always drop the same error. Firstly, he doesn't work as I would like to because my flags (into the .yml file) aren't working, here is my .yml file :

```
    name: Waka Readme

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    # Runs at 05:00PM UTC = 00:00AM +7
    - cron: '0 */4 * * *'

jobs:
  update-readme:
    name: Update this repo's README
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: anmol098/waka-readme-stats@master
        with:
          WAKATIME_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.WAKATIME_API_KEY }}
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          SHOW_LINES_OF_CODE: "True"
          SHOW_PROFILE_VIEWS: "False"
          SHOW_COMMIT: "False"
          SHOW_EDITORS: "True"
          SHOW_DAYS_OF_WEEK: "False"
          SHOW_LANGUAGE: "True"
          SHOW_OS: "True"
          SHOW_PROJECTS: "False"
          SHOW_TIMEZONE: "False"
          SHOW_LANGUAGE_PER_REPO: "False"
          SHOW_SHORT_INFO: "False"
          SHOW_LOC_CHART: "False"
          LOCALE: en
```

You can find the gh repo here : https://github.com/anmol098/waka-readme-stats

Here is the error that I'm having when I run the .yml file :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception Occurred Query failed to run by returning code of 401. 
  File "/main.py", line 497, in <module>
{
    user_data = run_query(userInfoQuery)  # Execute the query
    viewer {
  File "/main.py", line 156, in run_query
      login
    raise Exception("Query failed to run by returning code of {}. {}".format(request.status_code, query))
      email
Exception: Query failed to run by returning code of 401. 
      id
{
    }
    viewer {
  }
      login

      email
      id
    }
  }
```

PS: my Wakatime profile is working, I have no problem with the API Key, you can even find my stats here : https://wakatime.com/api/v1/users/branlito/stats/last_7_days

Comment: PS (2) : my gh action is passing correctly everytime but nothing is displayed in the readme file

Comment: did you try running from `action`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a GitHub API Token with repo and user scope from https://github.com/settings/tokens if you're running the action to get commit metrics

Answer (score 0):

in username you must use your username used on github

`![Github Wakatime Stats](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/wakatime/?&USERNAME&layout=compact&&theme=default&link="https://www.github.com/USERNAME/")`

Comment: It seems you decided to update this answer, but instead of making an [edit], you instead [posted a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687057/3025856). Given that, I assume this answer is no longer needed. **Can you delete this answer?**

Comment: no, because each code has a different statistic result, inside the user's Github.

Comment: Hmm. So given that you deleted the _other_ answer, I take it this is the one that gives the expected results? Regardless, typically contributors leave _one_ answer—even if it includes multiple parts—rather than multiple answers.